# Most efficient way to store historical records of two one-to-one tables?

Tags: database, database-design, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables, member and subscription. Say the schemas are as following

```
TABLE member {
  member_id integer [not null, pk]
  phone_number varchar(15) [not null, UNIQUE]
  membership enum(['STUDENT', 'STAFF', 'STAFF_SON']) [not null]
  name varchar(100) [not null]
  faculty varchar(64)
  email varchar(100)
}
```

and

```
TABLE subscription {
  member_id integer [not null, pk, ref: - member.member_id]
  active bool [not null]
  invoice varchar(256)
  subscription_date datetime [not null]
  expiration_date datetime [not null]
}
```

now, how to store historical records of the subscription table to keep track of a particular member's subscriptions changes over the course period? i.e., when a member renew their subscription.

I've tried many things but I doubt their efficiency.
Let's call it `subscriptions_record` and it should have a one-to-many relationship with `subscriptions`. Here's my first work around

```
TABLE subscription_records {
  id integer [pk]
  member_id integer [fk, ref: > subscription.member_id]
  invoice varchar(256) [fk, ref: > subscription.member_id]
  subscription_date datetime [fk, ref: > subscription.member_id]
  expiration_date datetime [fk, ref: > subscription.member_id]
}
```

Is this a good solution? I would appreciate any feedback or suggestions on how to improve my approach.

P.S. the database will contain 20k members at max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the `subscription_records` as an audit history of the subscription. If so, then I'd suggest to also add a `last_modified_datetime` and `last_modified_user` columns to it to record at what time and by who the subscription was changed last.

I'd put `active` column back in too; in case the user marked the `subscription` as inactive and then back to active ?

Could you `delete` a record from `subscription` ? if yes, then you'll have to think again if you want to have a foreign key on the `subscription_records` table.

Make sure that your insert/update/delete on the `subscription` and subsequently on `subscription_records` are done in one transaction

You might also want to throw in an index or two on the table depending on how to intend to query it.